# extract numbers using bash shell script and awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Data:

```
 61      -3.5527      1.00000
 62      -3.4695      1.00000
 63      -3.4545      1.00000
 64      -3.1462      1.00000
 65      -1.4512      0.00000
 66      -1.1737      0.00000
 67      -0.8792      0.00000
 61      -3.5590      1.00000
 62      -3.4763      1.00000
 63      -3.4557      1.00000
 68      -3.1533      1.00000
 69      -1.4382      0.00000
 70      -1.1616      0.00000
 71      -0.8638      0.00000
```

What i expect:

file1:

```
 64      -3.1462      1.00000
 68      -3.1533      1.00000
```

file2:

```
 65      -1.4512      0.00000
 69      -1.4382      0.00000
```

I want to get file1 and file2 by using simply bash shell and awk.
How do I find the two lines where the values of the 3rd column are changed from 1 to 0?
Thx in advance!

Comment: Some details might avoid the usual perl/grep/python/whatnot answers on an awk targeting question: What are the separaters between the columns? Tabs, spaces, mixed? Do you seek the equivalent of say `cat Data|grep -e '^64 ' > file1` ? Or is/are there sometimes space/s at the beginngin of the `Data` lines?

Comment: You have to explain what the criteria are for a record to get into one or the other file, or we have to guess. It would also help to show your own efforts, as currently this looks like you expect somebody else to do all your work.

Comment: You're right. Benjamin Sorry about that. I edited the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `awk` script:

```
NR == 1 { last = $3; }
last == 1 && $3 == 0 { print previous > "file1" ; print $0 > "file2" ; }
last != $3 { last = $3; }
{ previous = $0 }
```

This works as follows: If the line number is 1, record the third column as `last`. If last equals 1 and the third column of the current line equals 0, print the content of the variable `previous` to file1 and the current line to file2. If the value of `last` is not equal to the third column of the current line, change the value of the variable. Finally, record the current line as `previous`, for use in the second rule.

Since it isn't really necessary to intialize `last`, or to check whether the value of the third column has changed, the script can be shortened to:

```
last == 1 && $3 == 0 { print previous > "file1" ; print $0 > "file2" ; }
{ last = $3; previous = $0 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Michael
It works!
I'm wondering if previous and $0 are system variable... Could you explain little about your code?

Answer (score 1):

### Long version

```
awk '
  NR>1 && last==1 && $3==0 {
    print last_line > "file1"
    print $0 > "file2"
  }
  {
     last=$3
     last_line=$0
  }
' input.txt
```

### Short version

```
awk 'NR>1&&x==1&&$3==0{print y>"file1";print $0>"file2"}{x=$3;y=$0}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk  'BEGIN{prev=1; prevRec=""} prev == 1  && prevRec != "" && $3 == 0{print $0 > "file1";print prevRec > "file2"} {prev = $3; prevRec=$0}' file
```

Comment: While this might be technically correct you should explain what it does

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ tmp=match($3,/[1][.]?????/) ; if (tmp) { lineone=$0 ; newzero=0 ;} else if ( newzero <1) { onechanged[lineone]=1 ; zerochanged[$0]=1 ; newzero=1} } END { print "File1 is: " ; for (key in onechanged){ print key } ; print "File2 is:" ; for (key in zerochanged){ print key }}' test.txt
```

output is :

```
File1 is:
 64      -3.1462      1.00000
 68      -3.1533      1.00000
 File2 is:
 69      -1.4382      0.00000
 65      -1.4512      0.00000
```